# How can I write my own stream functions in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have written a simple Stream.unfold function, which works fine when I call it like this:

```
a = Stream.unfold({1,2,3}, &my_unfold_func) |> Stream.take(5)
```

However, I don't seem able to find a way of implementing a wrapper that would allow me to call my function directly, e.g. like this:

```
a = my_unfold_wrapper() |> Stream.take(5)
```

What I've tried is:

```
def my_unfold_wrapper(), do: Stream.unfold({1,2,3}, &my_unfold_func)
```

When I run this code, I get the error:

```
 #Stream<[enum: #Function<35.27730995/2 in Stream.unfold/2>,
 funs: [#Function<38.27730995/1 in Stream.take/2>]]>
 [Finished in 0.7s]
```

The problem seems to be that the Stream.take() is returning another stream, which I somehow need to execute to convert into an array. Replacing Stream.take with Enum.take seems to do the trick, which just leaves the question of how I can execute a stream.

Comment: This looks just fine, to debug this we would need more information. What is the specific error message you are getting? Can you please show us the definition of `my_unfold_func`?

Comment: The output produce when I run the 'new' code is as follows:#Stream<[enum: #Function<35.27730995/2 in Stream.unfold/2>,
 funs: [#Function<38.27730995/1 in Stream.take/2>]]>
[Finished in 0.7s] The problem seems to be that the Stream.take() is return another stream, which I somehow need to execute to convert into an array. Replacing Stream.take with Enum.take seems to do the trick, which just leaves the question of how I can execute a stream. Also, how can I insert new lines into SO comments? i.e. without terminating the comment?

Comment: Edit your question to include the error information you put in that comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've cracked it, kind-of. The follow code does pretty much what I want:

```
Foobar.my_unfold_wrapper()
|> Stream.take(10)
|> Stream.into(File.stream!("output.txt", [:write, :utf8]))
|> Stream.run
```

The only problem I have with this now is that the output is being concatenated onto one massive line - an issue that I have raised in a separate SO question.

Comment: This is the right way to run a Stream. If you want the stream values as well, you can get a list with `Enum.to_list/1` instead of `Stream.run/1`. But for writing to a file `Stream.run` is the right choice. To stream lines/add newlines to a file, you should add the `:line` option.

Comment: How do I add the line option to the File.stream! call? I've tried putting it in with the :write etc and also as a separate argument, before or after the other option list, but none of these approaches work.

Comment: Got it to compile with |> Stream.into(File.stream!("output.txt", [], :line))
but this didn't seem to have any impact. Now using a map function to append a new line to the end of each output line.

Comment: You are right, adding :line option should make no difference, as it is the default. It is probably only used for reading from the file stream. Sorry for the confusion!